# SaltStack Master download file from a webservice

Tags: salt-stack

Is there any of ordering a Salt Master to download a file ( in my case a python command file) from a  URL ?

I can trigger the sync to all the minions after to be sure it gets to everyone?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Did you mean: "Can I command the salt-master to download a file?"  If so, you can do this by also running salt-minion on the master.

Comment: Hey Dan, so the idea was like this : i have a libary with commands, that are exposed via a download link. I have salt-api up and running on the salt master, and  i wanted to know if salt has a command to download a file and store it somewhere. I did a bit of research and actually i will do like this : create a command dowload_file on the salt-master that goes to the library and downloads other commands. will trigger this via salt-api via runners. The idea was the my "source of truth" for the commands is a web service not the salt master _modules folder and wanted to have a sync mechanism.

Comment: "source of truth" in salt is the pillar system.  You could and maybe should create a stub module there to pull from your webservice.  See http://garthwaite.org/virtually-secure-with-openvpn-pillars-and-salt.html

Comment: How goes the battle?

Comment: Hey Dan, thanks for the followup and for the response. I did what i mentioned above: created new runner : download_module.py. With this runner im downloading modules from the webservice and the running a sync after the download is done. Its quick and dirty but gets the job done for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synthesis of the author's own solution:

1. Enable salt-api
2. Create a custom runner to download the file on the salt master with urllib2.urlget.
3. Trigger this runner via a salt-api request.
4. After the download is complete, use the salt-api to push payload onto the minions.